# How to implement Expandable ListView in xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview

I'm using service to get some values from json.
I displaying them on home page (IrrigNetPage) where I have three tabs, so I want to sort them on diferents way on every tab.

Here's my model:

```
public class IrrigNetModel
{
    public IrrigNetModelItem[] items { get; set; }
}

public class IrrigNetModelItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string DateText { get; set; }
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    public float StationLongitude { get; set; }
    public float StationLatitude { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a part of xaml code from View:

```
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Column="1"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="{Binding LocationTabColor}"
            Padding="10"
            Margin="1">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TabTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="location"/>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Image Source="{Binding LocationTabIcon}"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   WidthRequest="16"
                   HeightRequest="16"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   x:Name="LocationIcon"/>
            <Label Text="{i18n:Translate Location}"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   TextColor="{Binding LocationTabTextColor}"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

And, ofcourse here is part of ViewModel:

```
        else if (tabName == "location")
        {
            ServiceTabColor = Color.FromHex("#f4f4f4");
            LocationTabColor = Colors.MENU_SELECTED_ITEM;
            MapTabColor = Color.FromHex("#f4f4f4");

            ServiceTabIcon = "services.png";
            LocationTabIcon = "location_sel.png";
            MapTabIcon = "location.png";

            ServiceTabTextColor = Colors.MENU_SELECTED_ITEM;
            LocationTabTextColor = Color.FromHex("#ffffff");
            MapTabTextColor = Colors.MENU_SELECTED_ITEM;

            ListHederIcon = "location.png";

            IsListVisible = IsListVisible;
            IsGridHeaderVisible = true;
            IsMapVisible = false;

            if (ServiceName == "irrigNET")
            {
                FrameIcon = "service_irrig.png";
            }
            else
            {
                FrameIcon = "service_trap.png";
            }
            GroupServicesByLocation();
        }
```

Where I set some proporties values and as you can see here I call method GroupServicesByLocation(); which looks like:

```
    public void GroupServicesByLocation()
    {
        var groupedCollection = IrrigNetCollection.GroupBy(x => x.StationName);
    }



    public ObservableCollection<IrrigNetModelItem> IrrigNetCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IrrigNetModelItem>();
    public async void GetData()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        dialog.Show();
        var token = LocalData.Token;
        var data = await IrrigNetService.GetServices(token, "sr");
        var irrigNetModel = new IrrigNetModelItem();
        foreach (var d in data.items)
        {
            IrrigNetCollection.Add(d);
            if (d.ServiceName == "irrigNET")
            {
                IrrigCounter++;
                FrameImage = "service_irrig_img.png";
                FrameHeaderColor = Color.FromHex("#33A8F7");
                ServiceName = "irrigNET";
                FrameIcon = "service_irrig.png";
            }
            else
            {
                AlertCounter++;
                FrameImage = "alert.png";
                FrameHeaderColor = Color.FromHex("#2BB24B");
                ServiceName = "alertNET";
                FrameIcon = "service_trap.png";
            }                
        }
        dialog.Hide();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: A simple google search got me this  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-expendable-listview-app/ hope it helps

Comment: @G.hakim Thank's, but I already found it on Google, but still have problem how to implement in my case. Could you, please, give me some more help on mu code?

Comment: "still have problem" does not tell us anything.  What *specific* problem are you having incorporating this code into your project?

Comment: @Jason Still have a problem to implement it. Method GroupServicesByLocation()
group item correcltly (I see it using debuger > IEnumerator values) but still does not show anything diferent then default ortder of items.

Comment: You have still not told us what specific problem you are having!!  Please read "How to Ask" in the help section before posting.  And there is no method GroupServicesByLocation() in the code you posted.

Comment: @Jason Whops! I edited and added GroupServicesByLocation()...
Problem is that nothing happening.

Comment: groupedCollection is a local variable to GroupServicesByLocation and will go out of scope as soon as that method exits

Comment: @Jason is there any way to do something like `foreach (StationName in groupedCollection)
            {
                //add ListHederIcon + StationName + number of elements with same name
            }` in method?